# Lookup Column with Multiple Values creates Multiple Records

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, multiple-values

I have a field in my infopath form which allows a user to select multiple offices for a user to have access to.  This infopath form feeds a sharepoint list where processors can work requests for access.  If a user selects more than one office, is there a way for infopath to force sharepoint to create identical requests for each of the offices selected?  For Instance:

[image: Example of Infopath vs Sharepoint]

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath is used to customize the forms used for creating and editing items in a SharePoint list.

I don't think we could use InfoPath to force SharePoint to create list items.

As a workaround, I suggest you use workflow to extract lookup column in the source list then create new items in another OOB list.

Extract values from a multi-value enabled lookup column in workflow for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a8a890b5-f5fb-447f-b96f-9f3abdb7e178/forum-faq-sharepoint-2013-extracting-values-from-a-multivalue-enabled-lookup-column-and-merge?forum=sharepointgeneral